# headline is not positioning correct

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make a headline 2 and headline 3 like this:

[image]

As it is now the menubar under "kompetencer" looks like this: [mySite](https://vouzalis.com/test/test/)

I have tried to add the Headline 2 and 3 in the following code, but they are not on a straight line when I do it like this

```
<li class="dropdown mega-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Kompetencer</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-9">
                    <h4 class="title">Design</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="divider"></div>
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li ><a href="page-about.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>About Us 1</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-about-2.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>About Us 2</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-about-3.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>About Us 3</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-about-4.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>About Us 4</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-about-me.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>About Me</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-team.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Our Team - Options 1</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-team-2.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Our Team - Options 2</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-team-3.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Our Team - Options 3</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-coming-soon.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Coming Soon Page</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <h4 class="title">HEADLINE 2</h4>
                            <div class="divider"></div>
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li ><a href="kompetencer.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Kompetencer</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-contact.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Contact 1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <h4 class="title">HEADLINE 3</h4>
                            <div class="divider"></div>
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li ><a href="page-404.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>404 error</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-404-2.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>404 error - Parallax</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-affix-sidebar.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Sidebar - Affix Menu</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-left-sidebar.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Left Sidebar</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-right-sidebar.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Right Sidebar</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-two-sidebars.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Two Sidebars</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-two-sidebars-left.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Two Sidebars Left</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-two-sidebars-right.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Two Sidebars Right</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-no-sidebars.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>No Sidebars</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-sitemap.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Sitemap</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 hidden-sm">
                    <h4 class="title">Premium HTML5 Template</h4>
                    <p class="mb-10">The Project is perfectly suitable for corporate, business and company webpages.</p>
                    <img src="images/section-image-3.png" alt="The Project">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**Result**
[image: Result]

Can anybody see what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add at first column

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<h4 class="title">HEADLINE 1</h4>
                            <div class="divider"></div>
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li ><a href="page-about.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>About Us 1</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-about-2.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>About Us 2</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-about-3.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>About Us 3</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-about-4.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>About Us 4</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-about-me.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>About Me</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-team.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Our Team - Options 1</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-team-2.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Our Team - Options 2</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-team-3.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Our Team - Options 3</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="page-coming-soon.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Coming Soon Page</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

For this reason it looks strange first column in comparation with others

Edit: remove Design class that is above

Comment: Hello. Thank you a lot for your answer. But this is the same code as I have now?

Comment: You didn't added for first colum above divider <h4 class="title">HEADLINE 1</h4>

Comment: My mistake ,just move <h4 class="title">Design</h4> under <div class="col-sm-4"> and your problem is solved

Comment: Ah yes now it make sense. It is working now. Thank you a lot for that

Comment: @KrMa No problem, have a nice day!